# ディレクトリを丸ごとzipでダウンロードしたい

Tags: php

よろしくお願いします。

ディレクトリをまるごとzipでダウンロードしたいです。

Windows8.1
php 5.4.39
Apache 2.2.14
localでの実行です。

mysite
  |
  |-image
  |   |-image1.png
  |    
  |-file1.php
  |-file2.php

上記のような状態のものを、zipで圧縮してダウンロードすることが目標です。

コードは以下の通りです。

```
<php

//Zipクラスロード
$zip = new ZipArchive();

//Zipファイル名指定
$zipFileName = 'mysite.zip';

//Zipファイル一時保存ディレクトリ取得
$zipTmpDir = '/phpdocs/nonprothemes';

//Zipファイルオープン
$result = $zip->open($zipTmpDir.$zipFileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

if ($result !== true) {
    return false;
}

//処理制限時間を外す
set_time_limit(0);


/* ファイルパスを指定する処理 */

//mysite内のファイル一覧取得
//ディクトリパス格納用変数
$dir = null;
$dir = 'mysite/';

//ハンドル取得用変数
$handle = null;
//ファイル情報取得用変数
$file = null;
//ファイルパス指定用配列
$fpath_array = array();

//ディレクトリの存在確認、ハンドル取得
if(is_dir($dir) && $handle = opendir($dir))
{
    //ディレクトリ内のファイルを取得
    while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false)
    {
        //'.','..'を取り除く処理
        if($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            //ファイルパス指定
            $fpath_array[] = 'mysite/'.$file;
        }
    }
}

//ファイルパス指定
//$fpath_array = array('mysite/style.css','mysite/index.php');
/* ここまで */

//Zip追加処理
foreach ($fpath_array as $filepath) {
    //filename取得
    $filename = basename($filepath);

    //取得ファイルをZipに追加
    $zip->addFromString($filename,file_get_contents($filepath));
    $zip->addFile($filepath);
}

$zip->close();

// ストリームに出力
header('Content-Type: application/zip; name="' . $zipFileName . '"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zipFileName . '"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($zipTmpDir.$zipFileName));
echo file_get_contents($zipTmpDir.$zipFileName);

// 一時ファイルを削除しておく
unlink($zipTmpDir.$zipFileName);
?>
```

現在、

> Warning: file_get_contents(mysite/images): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php on line 62
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php:62) in
>   C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php on line 69
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php:62) in
>   C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php on line 70
>
> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /phpdocs/nonprothemesmysite.zip
>   in C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php on line 71
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php:62) in
>   C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php on line 71
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(/phpdocs/nonprothemesmysite.zip): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php on line 72
>
> Warning: unlink(/phpdocs/nonprothemesmysite.zip): No such file or
>   directory in C:\phpdocs\nonprothemes\file_dw.php on line 75

これらのエラーが出ています。

apacheの権限の問題なのかと思ったのですが、ネットで調べてみてもhttpd.confのどこにどう記述すればいいのかが分かりませんでした。

参考になるサイトなどありましたら教えていただきたいです。

XAMPPで動かしているときには正常に動いていましたが、XAMPPを消してApacheを入れなおしたら今回のようなことになってしまいました。

どのようにして解決したら良いでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

/********* 追記 ***********/
mysite/image(imageフォルダ)を消した場合、

(以下、パターン1)
mysite.zip
  |
  |-mysite
  |   |-file1.php
  |   |-file2.php
  |    
  |-file1.php
  |-file2.php

このような形でzipが出来上がりました。

ちなみに、

> $zip->addFromString($filename,file_get_contents($filepath));

こちらをコメントアウトした状態で実行すると、
(以下、パターン2)
mysite.zip
  |
  |-mysite
  |   |-file1.php
  |   |-file2.php

このような形でzipで出来上がります。

/********* 追記 ***********/

コードを修正した結果、
中身の無い(?)8KBのzipフォルダが作成されました。
ファイルを追加する所で代わりにファイルパスを表示した所、問題なくパスが来ていました。

以下コードです。

```
$dist = 'mysite.zip'; // 生成する圧縮ファイル名
$path = './mysite'; // 圧縮するパス
$zipTmpDir = '/phpdocs/nonprothemes'; // 一時パス


$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipTmpDir.$dist, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
addZip($zip, $path);
$zip->close();

function addZip($zip, $path) {
  if (is_dir($path)) {
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), ['.', '..']);
    foreach ($files as $file) addZip($zip, "$path/$file");
  } else {
    $zip->addFile($path);
  }
}

// ストリームに出力
header('Content-Type: application/zip; name="' . $dist . '"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $dist . '"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($zipTmpDir.$dist));
echo file_get_contents($zipTmpDir.$dist);

// 一時ファイルを削除しておく
unlink($zipTmpDir.$dist);
```

Comment: XAMPPで動かしていた時、`mysite/images`の中身もちゃんと圧縮できていましたか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
XAMPPで動かしていた時には問題なく圧縮できていました。

Comment: `Permission denied` というエラーではありますが、実際にはディレクトリ `mysite/images` を `file_get_contents()` したために起きたエラーです。また、後ろ2つのエラーはディレクトリを `$zip->addFile()` したために圧縮に失敗し、 `/phpdocs/nonprothemesmysite.zip` が生成されていないことによるものかと思います。これらはApacheやPHPの設定とは関係のない問題なので、ソースコードやmysite内の構造が変わっていないのであれば、XAMPPの頃から発生しているはずなのですが・・・。（php.iniの設定によってエラーが表示されなかった可能性はあります）

Comment: zipの作成に失敗してるんじゃないですかね。以下3点確認できますか？
(1) 実行時のカレントディレクトリを表示するとどうなるか (2) unlinkをコメントアウトしてZipが正しく作成されてるか (3) fpath_arrayの中身

Comment: take88さん、コメントありがとうございます。
(1)と(3)の確認方法が分からなくて試せていないのですが、(2)に関しましては質問欄追記内のパターン1のディレクトリの状態でzipが出来上がりました。

unaristさん、コメントありがとうございます。
XAMPPの頃と現在のphp.iniの状態は違うところが多くあるので、その線はありえるかもしれません。

Comment: [How to [recursively] Zip a directory in PHP? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php/1334949) こちらの回答の関数を使うとどうですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
呼び出し方がどうしても理解出来ないのですが、引数には何を指定しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決することが出来ました。
皆様コメントありがとうございました。

全てのファイルパスを、

> 圧縮したいフォルダ名/(サブフォルダ名)/ファイル名

このように統一して1つの配列にまとめ、addFileでzipに追加、圧縮という形になっています。
サブフォルダはいくつあっても問題ありませんでした。
空のサブフォルダが存在していてもエラーは出ません。
しかし、圧縮したzipには空のサブフォルダは作られません。
以下がコードです。

```
<?php

//Zipクラスロード
$zip = new ZipArchive();

//Zipファイル名指定
$zipFileName = 'mysite.zip';

//Zipファイル一時保存ディレクトリ取得
$zipTmpDir = '/phpdocs/nonprothemes';
$path = './mysite';
$path2 = 'mysite';

//Zipファイルオープン
$result = $zip->open($zipTmpDir.$zipFileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

if ($result !== true) {
  return false;
}

//処理制限時間を外す
set_time_limit(0);

//パス取得
$fpath_array_beta = array_diff(scandir($path), ['.', '..']);

// zip追加する本命のパスを格納する配列
$fpath_array = array();

// ディレクトリ判別
foreach ($fpath_array_beta as $key => $value) {
  if(is_dir("$path/$value")){
    // パス指定
    $path_sub = "$path/$value";
    // サブフォルダ内のファイル名取得
    $array_beta = array_diff(scandir($path_sub), ['.', '..']);
    // パスとして取得(元配列に追加)
    foreach ($array_beta as $key2 => $value2) {
      array_push($fpath_array,"$path2/$value/$value2"); 
    }
  }else{
    // ファイルの場合はそのまま追加
    array_push($fpath_array,"$path2/$value");
  }
}

// print "<pre />"; var_dump($fpath_array); print "<pre />";

//Zip追加処理
foreach ($fpath_array as $filepath) {
  $zip->addFile($filepath);
}

$zip->close();

// ストリームに出力
header('Content-Type: application/zip; name="' . $zipFileName . '"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zipFileName . '"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($zipTmpDir.$zipFileName));
echo file_get_contents($zipTmpDir.$zipFileName);

// 一時ファイルを削除しておく
unlink($zipTmpDir.$zipFileName);
```